# Generating address of a instruction using Code Segment and Instruction Pointer

Tags: x86-16, microprocessors, real-mode, memory-segmentation

Consider the Code Segment Address to be FE00 and Instruction Pointer to be ABBE. Shifting the Code Segment by 4 bits and Adding the Instruction pointer leads to an additional carry. How do we represent the generated address?

Comment: 8086 linear addresses are 20 bits wide; you need 2 registers and `adc` the carry-out from the low 16 into the high 4 bits.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Actually, since the 286 linear addresses in (Real/Virtual) 86 Mode are 21 bits wide, as the high bit can carry out of the low 20 bits. Thus A20 (the 21st address line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider the Code Segment Address to be FE00 and Instruction Pointer to be ABBE. How do we represent the generated address?

Either you represent the address as

- `0FE00h:0ABBEh`, its segmented form using two 16-bit numbers separated by a colon and always (segment - colon - offset)
- `00108BBEh`, its linear form using one 32-bit number

No matter your choice it will always require 2 word sized registers on 8086.

"The *instruction pointer* is an offset in the 64KB memory segment that starts at the linear address obtained from multiplying the value in the `CS` *code segment* register by 16 (same as shifting left 4 times)."

Calculating the linear address could be done inefficiently (but easy to understand) like this:

```
mov     ax, 0FE00h  ; The code segment
mov     dx, 16
mul     dx          ; "shifting the code segment by 4 bits"
add     ax, 0ABBEh  ; "adding the instruction pointer"
adc     dx, 0       ; Taking care of the additional carry
```

This linear address 00108BBEh uses 2 registers `AX` and `DX`. The `AX` register will hold the least significant part 8BBEh and the `DX` register will hold the most significant part 0010h. If you need to refer to the whole pair of registers you do it like `DX:AX`. So highWord - colon - lowWord.

Unlike with seg:off notation, this is just one 32-bit number split over 2 registers, no overlapping place values.  The low bit of the high half has place value 2^16 when we're talking about a flat 32-bit (or 20-bit) number, not a seg:off address.

Comment: Generally groups of registers that form a single wider value are described from most significant register to least significant register. So you'd generally see DX:AX (high word : low word). The Intel documentation has pretty much adopted that convention as well.

Comment: @MichaelPetch You're right. My mind must have slipped into thinking how the value is stored in memory...

Comment: If you were actually going to run this (especially on 8086) you'd avoid `mul` and manually do an extended-precision left shift.  For example, extract the top 4 bits into the bottom of another register one at a time in a loop with `shl` / `adc dx,dx`, or with `mov dl, ah` ; `shr dl, 4` (186) ; `mov dh, 0`.  Or if you have efficient shifts (not 1 count per clock) `mov dx, ax` ; `shr dx, 12`